# SQL Calculating time from last transaction for each ID

Tags: sql

Hello I'm stuck trying to calculate the difference in time between each transaction for each ID.

The data looks like

```
Customer_ID | Transaction_Time
1             00:30
1             00:35
1             00:37
1             00:38
2             00:20
2             00:21
2             00:23
```

I'm trying to get the result to look something like

```
Customer_ID | Time_diff
1             5
1             2
1             1
2             1
2             2
```

I would really appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? This can be solved using the `lag()` function. What is the data type of the `transaction_time` column?

Answer (score 1):

Most databases support the `LAG()` function.  However, the date/time functions can depend on the database.  Here is an example for SQL Server:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             datediff(second,
                      lag(transaction_time) over (partition by customer_id order by transaction_time),
                      transaction_time
                     ) as diff
      from t
     ) t
where diff is not null;
```

The logic would be similar in most databases, although the function for calculating the time difference varies.